# BambooHR Python GET Request returning Error 401

Tags: python, api

I am trying to fetch data from Bamboo HR API using python but it is returning me Error 401 (which as per their documentation means "Your API Key is missing"). I actually tried to do the same thing using Google Apps Script and there it is working perfectly fine. Can anyone please suggest what am i doing wrong here in python. Its driving me nuts.

Documentation Link - https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference#get-employees-directory-1

Following is the code I am using in Python

```
import requests

url = "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/companyDomain/v1/employees/directory"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic API-KEY"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Following is the code I used in Google Apps Script

```
function myFunction() { 
  var url = "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/companyDomain/v1/employees/directory";
  var apiKey = "API-KEY";
  var authHeader = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(apiKey + ":x");
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url, { "headers":{"Authorization": authHeader } } ); 
  var content = res.getContentText(); 
  Logger.log(res);
  Logger.log(content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your API key in the URL.

```
import requests

your_api_key = "your_api_key"

url = f"https://{your_api_key}:x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/subdomain/v1/employees/directory"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": your_api_key
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

df = r.json()

df= pd.json_normalize(df["employees"])
```

Then this will work

Comment: also worth pointing out this I didn't have this error until I used a "non-employee" users and its api key.